# Swift Closure compilation error

Tags: swift

I am a beginner in swift.

The following code does not have any compilation error

```
var test  =  { //no error
  return "String"
}
```

Whereas if I add the type String to the variable test as shown below, the compiler throws error "Function produces expected type string. Did you mean to call it with ()"

```
var test:String  =  { // error
    return "String"
}
```

As far as I know, swift is capable of type inference. Can someone please explain why the above code throws compilation error where the first one doesn't.

Thanks

Comment: Note that you can alt-click on a variable in Xcode to see its type – useful to see what Swift is inferring it to be. You'll see that in your first example, `test` is `() -> String`, not `String`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example, Swift correctly uses type inference to infer your closure as a zero-argument (`Void`/empty tuple `()`) closure with return value `String`: `() -> String`

```
var test  =  {
    return "String"
}

print(test.dynamicType) // () -> String
```

Whereas in your second example, you explicitly specify that the *type*  of `test` is `String`, which means the attempt to assign a closure of type `() -> String` to it will be a type mismatch.

The reason Swift asks you if you'd like to call the closure with `()` is that you can actually *call*  the closure a single time (much like you call a function with a function reference an an argument list `(...)`), using the return value of the closure (which is `String`) to assign an initial value to your `test` variable (which is of, just that, type `String`).

```
var test2: String  =  {
    return "String"
}() // ok! assign "String" to test2
```

Comment: @originaluser2 thanks!

Comment: No problem @dfri :)

Answer (score 2):

In the first example `test` has `() -> String` type, not `String`. To make it `String` you need to call the closure:

```
var test = {
    return "String"
}()
```

The same thing with the second one:

```
var test: String  =  {
    return "String"
}() // test is now String
```

Answer (score 0):

you try to assign a closure to a string variable.

If you want to type your variable explicitly as a block that returns a string, do

```
var test: () -> String  =  {
    return "String"
}
```

If you want the closure to return string and assign it to a string variable, execute the closure immediately

```
var test:String  =  {
    return "String"
}()
```